# Get number inside of a string and do a loop

Tags: c#, string, numbers

I want to get a number of a string, and separate the string and the number, and then, do a loop and call a method the number of times the string says.
The string has to have this structure: "ABJ3" (Only one number accepted and 3 characters before it)

This is my code, but it repeat hundred of times, I don't know why

```
            int veces = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < m.Length; i++)
            {
                if (Char.IsDigit(m[i]))
                    veces = Convert.ToInt32(m[i]);
            }

            if (m.Length == 4)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i <= veces; i++)
                {
                    m = m.Substring(0, 3);
                    operaciones(m, u, t);
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                }
            }
            operaciones(m,u,t);
            if (u.Length >= 14)
            {
                u = u.Substring(0, 15);
            }
```

Some help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to convert your m[i] ToString() right now you are sending the char value to Convert.ToInt32 and that is a much higher value (9 = 57 for example)

```
char t = '9';

int te = Convert.ToInt32(t.ToString());

Console.WriteLine(te);
```

This gives us a result of 9 but

```
char t = '9';

int te = Convert.ToInt32(t);

Console.WriteLine(te);
```

Gives us a result of 57

So you need to change

```
veces = Convert.ToInt32(m[i]);
```

to

```
veces = Convert.ToInt32(m[i].ToString());
```

Hope it helped.

Best regards //KH.

Comment: yup, it worked, but it returns veces + 2 times thanks for your fast reply

Answer (score 0):

You cannot convert the digits like this. You're overwriting them and taking only the last one. Moreover, you're taking its ASCII code, not digit value. You have to extract all digits first then convert them:

```
int position = 0;
int veces = 0;
string temp = ""
for (int i = 0; i < m.Length; i++) {
  if (Char.IsDigit(m[i]))
    position = i;
  else
    break;
}
veces = Convert.ToInt32(m.SubString(0, i + 1));
```

Alternatively, you can use regex instead.